# What does "Error in if (target < min(modVar)) { : the condition has length > 1" mean in a LOSEM analysis using OpenMX under R?

Tags: r, openmx

I want to conduct a LOSEM twin analysis using OpenMX under R. (It's used in behavioral genetics and twin studies to investigate the genetic and environmental influences on traits and behaviors).

My Variables:
a.res. and b.res(dependent variables [standardized]),z_age (age [standardized]), zygof1f2 (zygosity,MZ meaning monozygotic = 1, DZ meaning dizygotic = 2)

My Code:

```
\#Select dependent variables.
selDVs = c("a.res.", "b.res.")

\#Select moderator
moderator = "z_age"

\#Subset MZ and DZ data
mzData =subset(DS_HA, zygof1f2 =="MZ",c(selDVs, moderator))
dzData =subset(DS_HA, zygof1f2 =="DZ",c(selDVs, moderator))

\#Define LOSEM increments
targets = seq(from = -1.0, to = 2.0, by =.01)

\#Run and plot for specified windows
output\<-umxGxE_window(selDVs = selDVs, moderator = moderator, mzData = mzData, dzData = dzData, target = targets)
```

After executing the last command, the following error is displayed:

> Error in if (target < min(modVar)) { : the condition has length > 1

I don't understand the error or how to solve it.

Comment: You could check the `names()` of `mzData` and `dzData` to see if these datasets have indeed a single column called "z_age", and if `mzData$z_age` and `dzData$z_age` return vectors (check with `is.vector(...)`). It might also be worth a try to omit rows where "z_age" `is.na()` (see doc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug in the `umxGxE_window` function.  You should report it to the author.

The help page for `umxGxE_window` says that `target` can be "A user-selected list of moderator values to test (default = NULL = explore the full range)", so your use of `targets <- seq(from = -1.0, to = 2.0, by =.01)` should be okay.  But the function has the test in the error message, which is not legal when `target` is a vector like `targets`.

A workaround might be to put everything in a loop and pass in one target at a time, but that would be a lot of trouble, and might not give the result you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, that already helps a lot! The strange thing is that using `targets <- seq(from = -1.0, to = 2.0, by =.01)` worked in a paper I read. They also used R and uploaded their scripts to an OpenScience website, so I don't understand why it doesn't work for me. Do you think this will work on a different computer or after I uninstall and reinstall R? (Sorry if that's a stupid question but I only recently started working with R or codes in general)

Comment: It's only relatively recently that that error was detected by R, so maybe the paper was using an older version.  It has never worked the way it appears to be intended, but it used to just produce an incorrect result with a warning, and the warning could be suppressed.  The correct fix is to use something like `if (any(target < min(modVar)))`, but that's hard for a user to do, it's something the package author should do.